# Python Schedule module works only the first time

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, finance

I'm currently working as an quant intern in a financial company. What I'm trying to do is to let the system update today's stock market data into .csv every day at 16:30.

I searched online and found the Schedule module, seems quite easy so I implemented it. On the first day(Monday）, it did a good job and updated accordingly. However, today I check the server yesterday's (Tuesday) date was not updated and error was reported.

how I wrote my code is as follows:

```
def job():
    stockss = list(all_instruments(type='CS').order_book_id.values)
    for stock in stockss:
    d = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    a = rq.get_price(stock,str(d),str(d))
    df = pd.DataFrame(a)
    with open(str(stock)+'.csv','a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header = False)

schedule.every().monday.at("16:30").do(job)
schedule.every().tuesday.at("16:30").do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("16:30").do(job)
schedule.every().thursday.at("16:30").do(job)
schedule.every().friday.at("16:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

thank you!

Comment: Copy-paste your code instead of an image.

Comment: just did so, thanks for the advise, I'm new here..may I know do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Your code looks fine, especially if it ran successfully on Monday. Was your script still running when you checked on Wednesday? What was the error message?

Comment: I'm suddenly having the same issue after months of it working OK, were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another more powerful module `apscheduler`, here is an example:

```
# ... your import
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def job():
    stockss = list(all_instruments(type='CS').order_book_id.values)
    for stock in stockss:
    d = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    a = rq.get_price(stock,str(d),str(d))
    df = pd.DataFrame(a)
    with open(str(stock)+'.csv','a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header = False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(job, 'cron', day_of_week="mon-fri", hour="16", minute="30")  # run on Monday to Friday at 16:30
    print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Here is the related docs:

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html